# Toyota Kluger/highlander 2007 random engine knocking sound at start

Tags: toyota, rattle, highlander, engine-knock

Before I start, I have read this thread and it doesn't help [Toyota Highlander 2015 rattle sound at (cold) start](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/23648/toyota-highlander-2015-rattle-sound-at-cold-start).

For the past few months, my car started making a rattling/knocking sound (Don't exactly know what to call this sound) when the engine starts. But, it doesn't happen always and there is no specific pattern. It doesn't appear to be a starter motor problem either. Since it is random, the mechanics can't reproduce it.

I am attaching video links to three recordings where you can hear the sound easily.

https://youtube.com/shorts/5-acCN6g3YE?feature=share

https://youtube.com/shorts/VxSB91qMKig?feature=share

https://youtube.com/shorts/nSKsJCLHJVo?feature=share

Please help me understand what could be the problem.

Comment: Perhaps I'm having trouble on my end but none of these 3 videos seem to have an actual recording of the car starting.

Comment: @jwh20. must be a problem with your device.  I can hear the engine start and also the rattling sound.

Comment: @jwh20 Please use headphones. Hard to notice on speakers.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a fault with the starter motor.

The front bearing of the starter may be worn, allowing the shaft and/or pinion to rattle once it disengages from the ring gear on the flywheel.